# Pulling Access query into Excel through Excel VBA & ADODB connection

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ado

I have a macro in Excel VBA that creates an ADODB connection to an Access database, and pastes in the results of a predefined query into a sheet in the Excel workbook.

```
Dim Con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim iCols As Integer
Set Con = New ADODB.Connection
With Con
 .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
 .Open AccessDBPath
End With

Dim Query1 As String
Query1 = "the query is written here"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open Query1, Con

Sheets("Query1").Cells.Clear
Sheets("Query1").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    For iCols = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Sheets("Query1").Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = rs.Fields(iCols).Name
    Next
          'Close Recordset
            rs.Close
          'Close Connection
           Con.Close
```

Nine times out of ten, this works perfectly and pulls in the data just as expected. However, on occasion, the data that gets pasted in is incorrect.

When it is incorrect, it pastes the full set of correct data (about 40k rows), but adds a set of repeated lines (an extra few hundred rows that were already accounted for in the first 40k) with some seemingly random blank rows at the end of the table. I cannot seem to find out why this happens and was wondering if anyone else has ever come across a similar issue.

Like I said, the macro does work sometimes, and I'm unsure why certain times it works and pulls the data correctly and other times it does not.

Comment: I guess this would be hard to troubleshoot since, as you said, it works 9/10 times. But, have you ever been able to confirm the recordset object actually contains this extra unwanted data? Or is it possible something is going wrong with clearing out old data?

Comment: How would I confirm the recordset object contains the extra data? The sheet is cleared before pasting in the new data

Comment: Is this always running the same query string? Or can that vary? If that latter, try logging the query string. Maybe you can detect a pattern for when it fails.

Comment: Is this macro creating a new sheet or appending an existing?

Comment: It is always running the same query string. The workbook has a specific sheet that is used to dump this data into - it clears all data first to wipe anything currently in the sheet then makes the Access connection and pastes in the new data.